# How to write rigth it with Alamofire and RxSwift?

Tags: realm, alamofire, rx-swift

> How to write rigth it with Alamofire and RxSwift? I try to use
>   RxAlamofire but it's look so strange
>   How to write rigth it with Alamofire and RxSwift? I try to use
>   RxAlamofire but it's look so strange

My Json%

```
"session": {

   "sessionToken":  "16mpmthgkj6vjcco9u073fe61njhikbcn47s1co7bsfg110oefn4",  
   "refreshToken": "4ap0dqnuttpm5pv18njhthqv2d",  
   "expirationDate":"2016-10-17 03:44:28.826 +0000"       
},   
"profile":  
{

   "userId": "abUser$gT5d67g",  
   "userPhone": 380995392020,  
   "createdAt": "2016-08-14 03:44:28.826 +0000"  
}


    let registraion = request(.post, baseUrlDev + kRegUrl, parameters: phoneData, encoding:  JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: headers)
        .flatMap {
            $0
                .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json","text/html"])
                .rx.responseJSON()
        }

        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: {  response in
            let data = response.1
            let json = JSON(data)
            let sessionArray = json["session"]
            let userArray  = json["profile"]
            print(json)
           //here covert to json and save as realm object
            do{
                let session = Session()
                session.mToken = sessionArray["authToken"].string
                session.mRefreshToken = sessionArray["refreshToken"].string
                session.mExpirationDate = sessionArray["expirationDate"].string
                session.mExpired = false

                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(session, update: true)
                }
            }
            catch let err as NSError {
                print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
            }


        }).addDisposableTo
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please add more information on what you're trying to achieve here? What is your use case? Additionally, are you actually having any issues with Realm, or purely just RxSwift+Alamo?

Comment: with RxSwift+Alamofire

Comment: @Taras Where exactly is your problem with the code you posted?